# Separating out javascript file in angular från .net mvc view

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am currently buiilding in angular in our website writen in .Net MVC4, I have two problems:

1. Separating out the javascript file
2. Passing the serverside model data to the javascript file

Tried use `<script src="path"></script>` to include the js file seems does not work att all.

`@Model` in the View represent the data from serverside after page is rendered, when the form submits the ajax posts some data of the `Model` , i tried to store the serverside data in a `factory` called `modeldata` then inject it to the controller, but getting that `Error: $injector:unpr`:

```
 angular.module('searchPolicy').factory('modeldata', function () {
    var modelsession = @Html.Raw(Model.sessionno);

    return modelsession;
})


var app = angular.module('searchPolicy', []);

app.controller("getresult", ["$scope", "$http", "$compile", "$window", "modeldata", function ($scope, $http, $compile, $window, modeldata) {

    console.log(modeldata)

    //Submit and search policy
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.results = [];
        $("#svedea_spinner").show();
        console.log($scope.sessionno);
        $scope.data = {
            sessionno: "@Model.sessionno",
            saleschannelno: "@Model.saleschannelno",
            currentpage: "@Model.currentpage",
            AvtalDDJson: "@Model.AvtalDDJson",
            ForsakringsNr: $scope.forsakringsnr,
            FirstNamn: $scope.firstname,
            LastName: $scope.lastname,
            OrgNr: $scope.orgnr,
            SelectedAvtal: $scope.avtal.Value,
            SelectedSubBroker: $scope.broker.Value,
            SelectedStatus: $scope.status.Value,
            productName: "@Model.productName",
        };

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/umbraco/Surface/WinsureSearchSurface/PolicySearch",
            data: $scope.data
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            $scope.results = response.data.psr.results;

            $("#svedea_spinner").hide();
        }), function (response) {
            console.log("error");
            $("#svedea_spinner").hide();
        }
    }
}])
```

I bet someone would easily see the problem, would be much appreciated to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here in case anyone got the same problem,

to use Model data från server to anuglar:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model));
var app = angular.module('searchPolicy', []).value("viewModel", model);
```

To Separate angular in a view-specific js file need to add `httphandler` because for security reason, .Net does not allow access to /View :

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add path="/Views" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>      
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="JavaScript" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="/Views" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```